# @Value annotation is always NULL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am trying to get some values from my `application.yml` file using the `@Value` annotation in a `ServiceImpl` class, but variables with `@Value` annotation always stay `NULL` for some reason. Can someone please help me in fetching the values from the `application.yml` file using `@Value` annotation?

This is what is present in my `application.yml` file

```yml
aws:
  routeconfig: 
    rolearn: myrolearn
    bucketname: mybucket
    region: ap-southeast-1
```

These are the variables with `@Value` annotation which are always `NULL`

```java
@Value("${aws.routeconfig.rolearn}")
String routeConfigRoleArn;

@Value("${aws.routeconfig.bucketname}")
String bucketName;

@Value("${aws.routeconfig.region}")
String awsRegion;
```

Comment: The class where you are using @value must be managed by spring.Can you confirm that ?

Comment: That yaml doesn't look right, you can't have value rolearn and the following map bound to routeconfig. However, what you really need do is share a complete minimal example that recreates the problem.

Comment: 1. What is your folder structure? 2. Did you use `bootstrap.yml` or `application.properties` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your yml is incorrect.

```
aws:
    routeconfig: rolearn
        bucketname: mybucket
        region: ap-southeast-1
```

You are referencing bucketname and region under a parent object of routeconfig property.

If you want to reference all the values under `aws`, it should be like so:

```
aws:
    routeconfig: rolearn
    bucketname: mybucket
    region: ap-southeast-1
```

Then your `@Value` annotation should work.

You can also configure a property class like so and inject it:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws")
public class AwsConfig {

    private String routeConfig;
    private String bucketName;
    private String region;

    // getters and setter
}
```

Then instead of using `@Value` you can inject the AwsConfig class and retrieve the corresponding properties:

```
AwsConfig awsConfig;
awsConfig.getRouteConfig();
awsConfig.getBucketName();
awsConfig.getRegion()
```

wherever needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try formatting your yaml like this:

```
aws:
  routeconfig: 
    rolearn: myrole
    bucketname: mybucket
    region: ap-southeast-1
```

Also, make sure you have only two spaces for indention and no tabs.

Comment: @yash7696 is ServiceImpl defined as a spring bean or component?

Answer (score 0):

You check if you are doing something wrong.

There is no issue in **application.yml.**

```
aws:
  routeconfig: 
    rolearn: myrolearn
    bucketname: mybucket
    region: ap-southeast-1
```

Properties are loaded from application.yml file. It's working for me :

```
@Controller
public class Sample {
    
    @Value("${aws.routeconfig.rolearn}")
    String routeConfigRoleArn;

    @Value("${aws.routeconfig.bucketname}")
    String bucketName;

    @Value("${aws.routeconfig.region}")
    String awsRegion;
    
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void load() {
        System.out.println(routeConfigRoleArn);
        System.out.println(bucketName);
        System.out.println(awsRegion);
        
    }

}
```

Output on console :

```
myrolearn
mybucket
ap-southeast-1
```

If you are still not able to solve, then you can go for this solution below :

You can do in this way to load properties.

Create a custom class so as to load custom properties. For example:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aws")
public class AWSProps {

    private Map<String, String> routeconfig;

    public Map<String, String> getRouteconfig() {
        return routeconfig;
    }

    public void setRouteconfig(Map<String, String> routeconfig) {
        this.routeconfig = routeconfig;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AWSProps [routeconfig=" + routeconfig + "]";
    }

}
```

In the **pom.xml**, add this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Now to test, just create sample controller :

```
@Controller
public class Sample {
    
    @Autowired
    private AWSProps props;
    
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public void load() {
        System.out.println(props);
    }

}
```

Output : `AWSProps [routeconfig={rolearn=myrolearn, bucketname=mybucket, region=ap-southeast-1}]`

Comment: @yash7696 Is this ok ?